# Create KenBurns with minimum possible zoom

Tags: android, android-kenburnsview

I am using this [library](https://github.com/flavioarfaria/KenBurnsView)

I am trying to create app with minimal possible zoom.
In my application I have small area where the images are presented as slide show. But the images are big so when kenburns effect starts it it zoomed too much.

How can I set the zoom level ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your own `TransitionGenerator`. If you want the keep the random movement and control the zoom, a good place to start is to base your custom `TransitionGenerator` off [this one](https://github.com/flavioarfaria/KenBurnsView/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/flaviofaria/kenburnsview/RandomTransitionGenerator.java#L120). The highlighted line (120) uses a random zoom factor. Hardcoding it will do what you need.